# Many kernels, users with different set of available kernels, how to?

Tags: jupyterhub

I set up a hub on which several users have access to a lot of different kernels.
I would like to restrict access to kernels on user (or preferably group of) basis.
How can I make it?

Note that I don't want to install "private" kernels, only to control who can see/use some given kernels.